# German translation for "well-powered category"

Tags: translation, ct.category-theory

A category is called **well-powered** if the partial order of subobjects of any object is a set. Is there a German translation which is well-established in the literature? I don't want to use the English term in a German text.

Comment: I am curious whether there is something available in: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kriegl/Skripten/category.pdf

Comment: 'Teilobjekt' only occurs once so my guess is no.

Comment: @Torsten: "Unterobjekt". @Suvrit: No.

Comment: I nominate Wohltemperierte Klavier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pareigis and Schubert both use "lokal klein" in their textbooks.
Of course there is a clash with the other meaning of "locally small" (i.e. that
Hom(a,b) is always a set), but this is usually satisfied by their definitions
of category.

Comment: Hm, I don't like this clash. Perhaps I will use another term. Thanks for the reference.